# How can I migrate Flux stores to Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, flux, migrate, riot.js

How can I begin to port my Flux stores over to reducers to utilize redux? I'd like to do this slowly without crippling the rest of the application.

I've read through all the literature Redux provides on migration found here:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/MigratingToRedux.html

However it seems like it's extremely vague. My stores are an extension of a base store:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

const CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

class BaseStore extends EventEmitter {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  emitChange() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  }

  addChangeListener(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  removeChangeListener(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

}

export default BaseStore;
```

Here is an example of an actual store:

```
import Constants from '../constants';
import dispatcher from '../scripts/dispatcher';
import BaseStore from './base';

class ExampleStore extends BaseStore {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.exampleProperty = false;

    this.dispatchToken = dispatcher.register((payload) => {

      switch (payload.actionType) {

        case Constants.Example.EXAMPLE_CONSTANT:
          this.exampleProperty = !this.exampleProperty;
          this.emitChange();
          break;

        default:
          // no-op
      }

    });
  }

}

export default new ExampleStore();
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't an advice forum, do you have something specific you're asking?

Comment: Sorry to be a little rude here, but if you read the entirety of my question you would see my question at end following my background and code samples. "How can I begin to port my Flux stores over to reducers to utilize redux?". Very specific ;) Update – I moved my question to the beginning of the post for better clarity. Update2 – updated the title to a question rather than asking for tips.